# How to redirect to other page by checking any condition in controller?

Tags: jsp, redirect, controller

I want to redirect the page to another page using controller in java.Means firstly I want to check the condition.
This condition will go in one request mapping annotation.In only one request mapping how could I redirect to other page because my page is already returning some other model and view?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lead/*.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView lead(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String role = "IAP_LEAD";
      if(role!="IAP_LEAD"){
             return new ModelAndView("redirect:"+"/common_files/error.jsp");
         }
```

But its not working.

Comment: Can you show your code whatever you have write, from which location you want to redirect JSP or SErvlet ?

Comment: I have done the changes